# Non-equivalent spaces with the same homotopy groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, cw-complexes

It is well known that two topological spaces that have all homotopy groups isomorphic need not be weakly homotopy equivalent, because it might not be possible to construct a single map inducing all those isomorphisms.

1. I'm wondering about what kind of conditions on two spaces with the same homotopy groups (and $\pi_0$) could allow us to conclude that they are in fact weakly equivalent. The same question if instead of topological spaces we consider Kan complexes.
2. Somewhat related, can there be a proper class of topological spaces (or Kan complexes) all having the same homotopy groups but being pairwise not weakly equivalent?

Comment: Your terminology is nonstandard, especially in the context of Kan complexes or CW complexes.  In those contexts, to say that $X$ and $Y$ have the same homotopy type is (essentially by definition) the same as to say that there is a homotopy equivalence between them.  The conditions of having isomorphic homotopy groups is much weaker and does not have a standard name.  (There are some further issues if you work with completely general simplicial sets or topological spaces.)

Comment: Also, given a sequence of groups $G_n$, the theory of Postnikov towers makes it clear that there is only a set of homotopy equivalence classes of connected Kan complexes $X$ with $\pi_*(X)\simeq G_*$.

Comment: Point taken, I edited the terminology

Comment: For #1, for simply-connected spaces, you just need to know that the two spaces have the same k-invariants. The homotopy groups of a space $X$ tell you the layers in the Postnikov tower of $X$. The k-invariants tell you how the layers are glued together.

Comment: @A.S. There is a version of k-invariants that works for non simply connected spaces as well (they live in some cohomology with local coefficients). However even in the simply connected case the groups where the k-invariants live get really hard to understand in all but the simplest of spaces.

Comment: @NeilStrickland could you please elaborate on how Postnikov towers give a bound on homotopy equivalence classes?